# Finding an expectation involving the increment of a symmetric random walk

Tags: stochastic-calculus, expected-value, martingales, random-walk

I am given:

- $M_n$ is a symmetric random walk with $X_n=M_n-M_{n-1}$
- Since $X_n$ is the increment of a symmetric random walk, we know that $E[X_n]=0$

The question has two parts:

First, I want to get the following expectation: $g(\alpha)=E[e^{\alpha X_n}]$

I have tried using the definition of the expectation:

$g(\alpha)=e^\alpha*0.5 + e^{-\alpha}*0.5$

I was wondering if there is a way to simplify $g$ further by using $E[X_n]=0$?

Second part of the question asks us to show that $Y_n=exp\{\alpha M_n -n \log (g(\alpha))\}$ is a martingale.
I think I will have clearer idea how to tackle this one once I get the answer for the first part. But I was thinking of using the definition of martingale:

$E[Y_m-Y_n|F_n]=0$, where $m>n$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\exp$ using `\exp`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: To prove that $Y_n$ is a martingale write $$Y_n = \exp(\alpha M_{n-1}-n \log g(\alpha))\cdot \exp(\alpha X_n).$$ Use the pull out property of the conditional expectation and the independence of $X_n$ and $F_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You could write $g(\alpha)=\cosh\alpha$. There’s no further simplification using $E[X_n]=0$.